# How to show an image among text

Tags: floats, positioning

i am trying to show an image in the middle of a section as shown in the latex code posted below. the problem now is, the image always is displayed at the top
of the section "before the section starts" and i want it in the middle

please let me know how to do it correctly

> the question the moderator suggested, does not contain latex code that
>         might solve my issue plus, the explanation is really prolongated while, I
>         think, the solution of question could be solved with few words or few
>         lines of latex code

please re-activate the question

**latex**:

```
\subsection{OSM Vs Google Maps}
OpenStreetMap OSM which started in Univesity College London UCL .....
......
.....
......
\begin{figure}
\centering
\textbf{Your title}\par\medskip
\includegraphics[width=100mm,scale=0.7]{osm_vs_wikipedia_1}
\caption{Your caption}
\end{figure}

the rest of the text goes here..
...
```

Comment: The question isn't closed yet. However, see [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) and [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625)

Comment: And while I agree that the accepted answer to the question @egreg mentions doesn't answer your question, the [other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39019/586) actually does.